# PHP session_destroy()

Tags: php, session

In my application, when the user logs out, I want to destroy all the current user's sessions. Do I unset each session used in the application and then call session_destroy() or just call session_destroy()?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, by "sessions", do you mean indices of the `$_SESSION` variable?  Or actually user sessions?

Comment: All current user's sessions set within the application.

Comment: @Scott W: Then `session_destroy()` itself won't cut it.  My I ask why you want to log everyone out when only one user logs out?

Comment: Jonah, I think you misunderstood my question. As it is stated in my question, I only want destroy the current user's sessions upon logging out.

Comment: OK I see, I made a typo. I said users instead of user's. My bad...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `session_destroy()` function should unset all sessions that you have set. So yes, you should only have to call that. You can test it by calling `session_destroy()` then trying to echo a session value, if it echoes then it's not worked, if an error of some description appears, then the session has successfully been destroyed.

Comment: `session_destroy()` only destroys the _current_ session, not all.  http://php.net/session-destroy

Comment: Brad, Thank you! Using session_destroy() alone works fine, I just wasn't sure if that was the only thing I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

`session_destroy()` does not destroy all user's sessions.  You would need to write to a persistent storage media (database, text file, etc.) and then call `session_destroy()` to kill it's own session.  Then, have all pages check it when they load.  If it has some special command in it (for example, normal is `0`, destroy command is `1`), have them call `session_destroy()`.

Comment: Jonah, which sessions are not destroyed? Do they remain functional?

Comment: @Scott W: All but the current one.  Yes.  Each person visiting the site has his/her own session.  `session_destroy()` only destroys one of them, not all.

Answer (score 0):

**session_unset():** Remove all session vars. In the **1rst F5** no longer display the session variables.

**session_destroy():** Delete the current session. In the **2dn F5** no longer display the session variables.

Therefore your logout.php script could be:

```
<?php
session_start();

...

// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy();

// Redirect to home
header("Location: home.php");
exit();
```